# Is Application_Start of Global.asax is called by iis on wcf application when the iis is the host ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, iis-7

I have wcf application that is hosted by iis. 
I add the Global.asax file with implimentation of the Application_Start.

But when i start the iis ( or reset ) i don't see that the Application_Start method is called.

How to fix it ? 
I want that the iis will call this method on iis start (when the computer startup ( because the iis start automatic on machine start ) or when iis restart )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the WCF Service is hosted on the IIS on a website, then the Application_Start Method should be called. However, **by default application pool wouldn't start until the Application Pool** receive the first request.

So, until you make a call to WCF Service, the Application_Start method wouldn't be called.

Also, IIS offer **Application Initialization Module**, which can be used to issue a Fake Request to the website by the IIS Server so that Application can start Automatically once the IIS Starts. It also allows for custom warm-up code for the Application. You can read more detail [here](https://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization).

Answer (score 3):

WCF doesn't work like that. It's a per-call service and as so handling requests on demand...

A little more details can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/739674/444665

However you might be able to solve your wish through this solution [Running a function on WCF start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841635/running-a-function-on-wcf-start-up)