# Method or function called on the start of web service from IIS?

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Is there any method or function which is called when the web service(.net framework 3.5) is started from the IIS, without any request from the client side?

I want a function or method in my code which should be called when the service is started from IIS server.

Application start is called when I am browsing the service from the IIS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a function on WCF start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841635/running-a-function-on-wcf-start-up)

Comment: its a web service which is in .net framework 3.5