# How to configure Application Insights with instrumentation keys from multiple environments in WCF?

Tags: c#, azure, wcf, azure-application-insights

If I set up my WCF project with an `ApplicationInsights.config` file as outlined in [this Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-application-insights-manually), and data is logged to Application Insights (using the hardcoded instrumentation key) as expected.

#### Is there any way to specify instrumentation keys on a per-environment basis when using the ApplicationInsights.config file?

The config file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ApplicationInsights xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ApplicationInsights/2013/Settings">
 <TelemetryInitializers>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.HttpDependenciesParsingTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureRoleEnvironmentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.BuildInfoConfigComponentVersionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.WebTestTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SyntheticUserAgentTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web">
     <!-- Extended list of bots:
           search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|BrowserMob|BingPreview|PagePeeker|WebThumb|URL2PNG|ZooShot|GomezA|Google SketchUp|Read Later|KTXN|KHTE|Keynote|Pingdom|AlwaysOn|zao|borg|oegp|silk|Xenu|zeal|NING|htdig|lycos|slurp|teoma|voila|yahoo|Sogou|CiBra|Nutch|Java|JNLP|Daumoa|Genieo|ichiro|larbin|pompos|Scrapy|snappy|speedy|vortex|favicon|indexer|Riddler|scooter|scraper|scrubby|WhatWeb|WinHTTP|voyager|archiver|Icarus6j|mogimogi|Netvibes|altavista|charlotte|findlinks|Retreiver|TLSProber|WordPress|wsr-agent|http client|Python-urllib|AppEngine-Google|semanticdiscovery|facebookexternalhit|web/snippet|Google-HTTP-Java-Client-->
     <Filters>search|spider|crawl|Bot|Monitor|AlwaysOn</Filters>
   </Add>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ClientIpHeaderTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AzureAppServiceRoleNameFromHostNameHeaderInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationNameTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.OperationCorrelationTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.UserTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AuthenticatedUserIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AccountIdTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.SessionTelemetryInitializer, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
 </TelemetryInitializers>
 <TelemetryModules>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector">
     <ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
       <!-- 
       Requests to the following hostnames will not be modified by adding correlation headers.         
       Add entries here to exclude additional hostnames.
       NOTE: this configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
       -->
       <Add>core.windows.net</Add>
       <Add>core.chinacloudapi.cn</Add>
       <Add>core.cloudapi.de</Add>
       <Add>core.usgovcloudapi.net</Add>
     </ExcludeComponentCorrelationHttpHeadersOnDomains>
     <IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
       <Add>Microsoft.Azure.EventHubs</Add>
       <Add>Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus</Add>
     </IncludeDiagnosticSourceActivities>
   </Add>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.PerformanceCollectorModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector">
     <!--
     Use the following syntax here to collect additional performance counters:

     <Counters>
       <Add PerformanceCounter="\Process(??APP_WIN32_PROC??)\Handle Count" ReportAs="Process handle count" />
       ...
     </Counters>

     PerformanceCounter must be either \CategoryName(InstanceName)\CounterName or \CategoryName\CounterName

     NOTE: performance counters configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.

     The following placeholders are supported as InstanceName:
       ??APP_WIN32_PROC?? - instance name of the application process  for Win32 counters.
       ??APP_W3SVC_PROC?? - instance name of the application IIS worker process for IIS/ASP.NET counters.
       ??APP_CLR_PROC?? - instance name of the application CLR process for .NET counters.
     -->
   </Add>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AppServicesHeartbeatTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.AzureInstanceMetadataTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
     <!--
     Remove individual fields collected here by adding them to the ApplicationInsighs.HeartbeatProvider 
     with the following syntax:

     <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.Tracing.DiagnosticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights">
       <ExcludedHeartbeatProperties>
         <Add>osType</Add>
         <Add>location</Add>
         <Add>name</Add>
         <Add>offer</Add>
         <Add>platformFaultDomain</Add>
         <Add>platformUpdateDomain</Add>
         <Add>publisher</Add>
         <Add>sku</Add>
         <Add>version</Add>
         <Add>vmId</Add>
         <Add>vmSize</Add>
         <Add>subscriptionId</Add>
         <Add>resourceGroupName</Add>
         <Add>placementGroupId</Add>
         <Add>tags</Add>
         <Add>vmScaleSetName</Add>
       </ExcludedHeartbeatProperties>
     </Add>

     NOTE: exclusions will be lost upon upgrade.
     -->
   </Add>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.DeveloperModeWithDebuggerAttachedTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnhandledExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.UnobservedExceptionTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">
     <!--</Add>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.FirstChanceExceptionStatisticsTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer">-->
   </Add>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.RequestTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web">
     <Handlers>
       <!-- 
       Add entries here to filter out additional handlers: 

       NOTE: handler configuration will be lost upon NuGet upgrade.
       -->
       <Add>Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.Tracing.RequestDataHttpHandler</Add>
       <Add>System.Web.StaticFileHandler</Add>
       <Add>System.Web.Handlers.AssemblyResourceLoader</Add>
       <Add>System.Web.Optimization.BundleHandler</Add>
       <Add>System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory</Add>
       <Add>System.Web.Handlers.TraceHandler</Add>
       <Add>System.Web.Services.Discovery.DiscoveryRequestHandler</Add>
       <Add>System.Web.HttpDebugHandler</Add>
     </Handlers>
   </Add>
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ExceptionTrackingTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
   <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.AspNetDiagnosticTelemetryModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
 </TelemetryModules>
 <ApplicationIdProvider Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.Implementation.ApplicationId.ApplicationInsightsApplicationIdProvider, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
 <TelemetrySinks>
   <Add Name="default">
     <TelemetryProcessors>
       <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.PerfCounterCollector.QuickPulse.QuickPulseTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector" />
       <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.AutocollectedMetricsExtractor, Microsoft.ApplicationInsights" />
       <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
         <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
         <ExcludedTypes>Event</ExcludedTypes>
       </Add>
       <Add Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.AdaptiveSamplingTelemetryProcessor, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel">
         <MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>5</MaxTelemetryItemsPerSecond>
         <IncludedTypes>Event</IncludedTypes>
       </Add>
     </TelemetryProcessors>
     <TelemetryChannel Type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.ServerTelemetryChannel, Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel" />
   </Add>
 </TelemetrySinks>
 <!-- 
   Learn more about Application Insights configuration with ApplicationInsights.config here: 
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=513840
 -->
 <InstrumentationKey>your-instrumentation-key-here</InstrumentationKey>
</ApplicationInsights>
```

My web.config contains the following:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.7.2" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule" type="Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation.TelemetryCorrelationHttpModule, Microsoft.AspNet.TelemetryCorrelation" />
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
```

[This documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/configuration-with-applicationinsights-config#instrumentationkey) suggests that I can set the instrumentation key in code (such as in an `AppInitialize` method as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10841635/running-a-function-on-wcf-start-up#answer-10841661)), but it doesn't seem to work.

```
TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
configuration.InstrumentationKey = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While there appear to be some caveats to this solution (depending on your hosting strategy), it is sometimes possible to add a `Global.asax`, and use the `Application_Start` hook to inject your configuration (This answer assumes you're using config transforms).

For example:

```cs
using System;

namespace SomeWcfThing
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey =
                System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["InstrumentationKey"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct approach is to use TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault() method to load any config from disk, then set/change additional values on the generated configuration.

Once the TelemetryConfiguration instance is created pass it to the constructor of TelemetryClient to create the client and start logging.