# NServiceBus with Castle Windsor and its Lifestyles

Tags: castle-windsor, nservicebus

We're currently running our WCF services in a WAS environment and host NServiceBus in the same host by using App_Code\InitializeService.AppInitialize()

All works fine until we want to use our container in our message handlers with registrations lifestyled as PerWcfOperation. These registrations are out-of-scope for the bus, which is logical.

We are now looking for a way to

1. Use the same container for the WCF services and NServiceBus
2. Clone or partially reuse the container we have in the WCF service for NServiceBus

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are you bootstrapping the container?  How does AppInitialize() get called?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/329936/when-appinitialize-method-get-invoked-in-asp-net will answer your question about the bootstrapping

Comment: Have you tried passing the instance of the container into the NSB initialization code?