# Autofac WcfIntegration - WCF client service can not be activated when communicating over net.tcp

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a **WCF client service** hosted under IIS 7 and using Autofac's WCF Integration. This service is called by another WCF service, using **basic Http Bindings**. Everything has worked *well* since the service started being used, about 3 months ago.

However, when I try calling this service over net.tcp, I am able to do it and receive callbacks for a period of time (about 8 hours usually) after that I keep receiving this error:

> The requested service, 'net.tcp://ecomsvc.webhost.com:12345/EcomSvc.svc' could not be activated.

Exception from the hosting server is:

> Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/EcomSvc.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: The AutofacServiceHost.Container static property must be set before services can be instantiated.. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The AutofacServiceHost.Container static property must be set before services can be instantiated.

Service's markup:

`<%@ ServiceHost
    Service="EcomService.Contract.IEcomSvc, EcomService.Contract"
    Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" %>`

Autofac registration:

```
private static void SetupDependencyContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register service implementations.
        builder.RegisterType<EcomSvc>().As<IEcomSvc>();

        // Set the dependency resolver.
        var container = builder.Build();
        AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
    }
```

The WCF service calling the client from above Autofac registration:

```
private static void SetupDiContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // Register service implementations
        builder.RegisterType<HandlerSvc>().As<IHandlerSvc>();
    builder.RegisterType<HandlerService().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        ConfigureServices(builder);

        //register other dependencies
        builder.RegisterType<ProxyCache>().As<IProxyCache>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        // Set the dependency resolver.
        var container = builder.Build();
        AutofacHostFactory.Container = container;
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        RegisterService<IEcomSvc>(builder, "EcomServiceTCP"); 
    }

    public static void RegisterService<T>(ContainerBuilder builder, string endpoint)
    {
        builder.Register(c => new ChannelFactory<T>(endpoint))
            .SingleInstance();

        builder.Register(c => c.Resolve<ChannelFactory<T>>().CreateChannel())
            .As<T>().UseWcfSafeRelease();
    }
```

Markup:

```
<%@ ServiceHost
Service="HandlerService.IHandlerSvc, HandlerService"
Factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory, Autofac.Integration.Wcf" %>
```

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens because you do the Autofac registration in the `Application_Start()` method of the `Global.asax` of the WCF-service.

`Global.asax`is HTTP-only. To be binding-agnostic (e.g. TCP) you need another starting-point of the WCF-service.

One option is the `AppInitialize`-method. Create an `App_Code` folder in the root of your WCF-service and add a class (the name is not important) and add a method with this signature `public static void AppInitialize()`.

The code in this method will be executed when the service starts, regardless of the binding used to trigger the service. You can put the Autofac-registration here.

More information about `AppInitialize` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/329936/when-appinitialize-method-get-invoked-in-asp-net).